# how to get a pointer to head of std::set in c++

Tags: c++11

how can i get a pointer to the first element in a set

```
   int main()
   {
    std::vector<int> v ;
    v.insert(v.end() , 1);
    v.insert(v.end() , 2);
    v.insert(v.end() , 5);
    v.insert(v.end() , 4);

    std::set<int> s ;

    s.insert(s.end() , 754);
    s.insert(s.end() , 5);
    s.insert(s.end() , 3);
    s.insert(s.end() , 4);

    std::list<int> l ;

    l.insert(l.end() , 45);
    l.insert(l.end() , 5);
    l.insert(l.end() , 3);
    l.insert(l.end() , 4);

    int *p = (int*)(&*l.begin());  <<<<<<-------- ( here )
    cout << *p++ <<endl;
    cout << *p++ <<endl;
    cout << *p++ <<endl;
    cout << *p <<endl;
```

it work with vectors but it gives me a junk value with set and list 
any idea ??

Comment: If you treat a pointer to something as a pointer to something else, you can get garbage (undefined behavior).  Is there a question here?

Comment: is there any way to do that without using iterator ?

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful with pointer arithmetic and containers. std::vector uses contiguous memory, and pointers will work as expected. Other containers may not store information in contiguous memory, and incrementing a pointer can fail to iterate through the container.

Use iterators instead. for example:

```
std::set<int> s;
//add stuff to the set
auto setit = s.begin(); //setit is an iterator for s
cout << *setit++ << endl;
//etc.
```

Iterators know how to traverse a container, and can be used similar to pointers, though there are differences. It is worthwhile to read the documentation about the container you're planning to use--find out what types of iterators can be used, and which operations invalidate an iterator.

For example, read the [documentation for std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). It describes which types of iterators can be used. It also, in the documentation for each of the modifiers, tells whether iterators are invalidated. If you are using `insert`in a set for example, iterators are not invalidated.

Comment: the idea is that i have to create my own iterator class

Comment: that's different from your question. You should ask a new question rather than changing this one, as you are changing the question enough to invalidate valid answers to the original question. Be specific about designing an iterator for a standard container.

Comment: Ask a new question, and focus on what you are trying to accomplish rather than on what you think you need to accomplish it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem .

Answer (score 0):

@rsjaffe is right, you should use an `iterator`.

But moreover, you are using objects.

These objects have some responsabilities, namely storing things with some garantees.

Vaguely :

- fast read/write access to items for `std::vector`
- auto-sorting and keep one when inserting for `std::set` (and relatively quick insertion and retrival ...)
- fast insertion/deletions for `std::list`

The goal of these classes is to those concepts work, and at the same time, to hide their internal working.

Analogically, you have a nice remote with nice buttons, but you can't know how they work, and the manufacturer offers no garantees it will work the same way overtime. You just know it works (Or you can test it, if you wish).

In the same way, `Iterators` are **things** that encapsulate **collections transversal**.

There is no such thing as a *pointer to a head* in a `std::set`, because the elements are not kept that way.

In that perspective, casting a `std::vector::iterator` to a pointer works *by accident*, and the question is irrelevent.

Answer (score 0):

Because the memory layout of vector is contiguous memory locations of the type of the contained elements so the pointer created is a normal C pointer.

For the set and list the contained elements are a part of a struct. For list it could be like this:

```
struct list {
  int value;
  struct list *next;
}
```

or

```
struct list {
  struct list *next;
  int value;
}
```

looks very C like without the templates and methods. So when you take the address the struct, you can read the value or the next pointer, but when you increment the pointer to int, you will get a garbage value if you hadn't one already.

In the case of set and list it wouldn't even help you to have the right type of the pointer ie. pointer to struct list, as they are not contiguous in memory so incrementing them would not get the right value.